# Why is dh$(k(x))=$dim $X$?

Tags: homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $X$ be an integral Noetherian scheme. Let $x\in X$ be a regular closed point of $X$. Then Huybrechts and Lehn in his book, says that dh$(k(x))=$dim $X$. Here dh$(k(x))$ refers to the homological/projective dimension of the $\mathcal{O}_x$-module (vector space in this case) $k(x)$. I have not been able to prove this.

I have tried the following. The Auslander-Buchsbaum formula for a module M over a  regular local ring $A$ is given by : $\mathrm{dh}(M)+\mathrm{depth}(M)=\mathrm{dim}(A)$.

depth($k(x)$)=0 since $k(x)$ is field. Therefore dh$(k(x))$=dim($\mathcal{O}_x)$=height$(\mathcal{m})$, where $\mathcal{m}$ is the maximal ideal corresponding to the point $x$ in an affine say Spec$(A)$ containing $x$. But why is this equal to dim$(X)$. The fact that $x$ is a regular closed point is to be used. But I am not able to proceed.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct and gives the first equality in the chain
$$\text{projdim}_{{\mathscr O}_{X,x}}(k(x))=\text{dim}({\mathscr O}_{X,x})=\text{codim}(\{x\},X)\leq\text{dim}(X)$$
in which the second equality can be checked directly for $X$ affine, and in which the third inequality is clear *but strict in general*: Take $R$ a discrete valuation ring with prime $\pi$, $X=\text{Spec}(R[T])$ and $x=(\pi T - 1)$. Then $X$ is regular integral of dimension $2$ and $x$ is a closed point since $$R[T]/(\pi T - 1) = R_{(\pi)} = \text{Quot}(R)$$ is a field. However, we have $\text{dim}({\mathscr O}_{X,x})=\text{height}_{R[T]}((\pi T-1))=1$ by the principal ideal theorem.

This is taken from Exercise 2.5.3 from Liu's book *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*.

If $X$ is a integral variety over a field, however, you *do* have $\text{codim}(\{x\},X)=\text{dim}(X)$ for a closed point $x$.

Comment: +1: this is an excellent answer. However it presupposes that $X$ is an algebraic scheme over some field, as you point out, and this is not part of the hypothesis. I don't know if the result is true for general integral schemes and although I can't find a counterexample, I am not especially convinced it is.

Comment: Dear Georges, thank you! Isn't $\text{Spec}(R[T])$ from the answer a counterexample for the general case?

Comment: Dear Hanno: yes your counterexample is indeed  absolutely correct and is exactly what I had been looking for. I am unforgiveable because I had thought of your counterexample before you posted your answer and had stupidly convinced  myself that it doesn't work. But it works beautifully and it is a pity I can't upvote you again!

Comment: Also, a zany consequence of your answer is that a discrete valuation ring cannot be finitely generated over some subfield!

Comment: @Hanno, thanks for that great answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is consequence of the following fact : Let $(A,\mathfrak m,k)$ be a noetherian local ring. If $\operatorname{inj dim}_A k$ is finite, then $A$ is regular, where $\operatorname{inj dim}_A k$ is the injective dimension. As far as I remember, one variation on this assertion is called "global dimension theorem", referring to a (JP) Serre's result on the subject.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand fully. Global dimension says that a Noetherian local ring $A$ is regular if and only if it has finite global dimension, in which case the global dimension coincides with the Krull dimension of $A$. So here, $gd(\mathcal{O}_x)=dim(\mathcal(O_x)$ since $\mathcal{O}_x$ is regular. But I want to prove that $dim(\mathcal{O}_x)=dim X$. How do I get that?

Comment: See http://www.math.utah.edu/vigre/minicourses/algebra/spiroff2.pdf, more specifically the Auslander-Buchsbaum-Serre theorem. It shows that the height of $\mathfrak{m}$ is the dimension of $X$. If I open EGA today, I'll manage to give you the reference.

Comment: poorna is right: this does not prove that $dh(k(x))=dim (X)$ .

Comment: ...and Hanno provides a counterexample.